# Python/Brython create button on a website

Tags: python, tampermonkey, brython

Is it possible to create a button on a website (like tampermonkey scripts do) with Brython ? Or is there an alternative to Tampermonkey(JavaScript), based on python(or similar) ?

My knowledge of JavaScript is 0 , thats why i'm avoiding it.

Thanks.

Comment: Or better ... Can anyone point me to the direction on how can i inject the brython scripts in a Tampermonkey script ? If it is possible ofcourse ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are set on using Python I would try to use a language converter like this:
http://www.brython.info/tests/precompile.html

You can then take the output and paste it into a tampermonkey script.

Comment: maybe i have arrived here 2 years too late, but this website does not exist....  is there an alternative solution ?